# Is benzoyl peroxide as body wash less effective than creams?

Tags: medications, effectiveness, acne, benzoyl-peroxide

For severe acne, wouldn't it be most effective to contact and subject the affected areas to Benzoyl Peroxide (BPO) for as long as possible? If yes, then ought it not be applied as a cream?

As a body wash, it'd be washed off the skin after 2 minutes. How can 2 minutes suffice for definitively killing bacteria?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I can think of numerous things that definitively kill bacteria in less than 2 minutes and are safe to apply to the skin.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3016935/pdf/jcad_1_4_48.pdf may help with your question